# Can I work on a branch with patches merged from another branches?

Tags: git, version-control, github, git-branch, git-merge

I'm not exactly sure what this is called or if it's a bad idea, so please educate me if I'm going about asking the wrong question.

I have a codebase that I'm helping to improve which I've cloned from github. I wanted to start by cleaning up some of the obvious warnings being reported by Eclipse and then to go through and clean out all of the deprecated member calls.

To help simplify things for the author, I want to submit multiple pull requests for similar modifications in the code rather than one "lots of stuff cleaned up" so it will be easier for them to inspect and approve.

What I have been doing is keeping their original code as master and making new branches off of it for each group of like-changes. The problem I'm having is that it's very confusing to work through the list of warnings/errors being reported by the IDE since every time I move to a different group, I switch back to a branch off of the master and problems which I've fixed in another branch are again visible.

Is it possible to just work on one big "everything" branch so that it's easier to ignore things I've already fixed? For example, every "commit" would be made into a separate branch off of the master.

Or.. work on a branch with all of my other branch-fixes merged in and then unmerge them when I'm done with the changes I've made elsewhere.

Does what I'm asking make sense? Is there a workflow for this?

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to do (but with a catch) is to create new branches based on your own branches instead of `/master`. For example:

```
git checkout -b obvious-warnings origin/master
# work work work, create PR

git checkout -b deprecated-calls
# work work work

git checkout -b fix-findbugs
# work work work
```

There is just one catch. Notice that I only put "create PR" after the first branch, not the others. You should only create the next PR after the previous one is already accepted. This way, only the new commits will show up in the diff for the reviewer.

This is simple, and I use this in practice every day in my projects.

Don't get me wrong, I normally create new branches based on `origin/master`, but only in the special case when a new branch depends on a pending PR, I create the new branch based on that PR branch.

Comment: So if you base new branches on a branch that is already in a PR, then the new branches show up on the original PR, right? Wouldn't it be nice if those new branches showed up in a different PR so that the maintainer could accept them in any order? I guess there's a real technical problem here to do with developing in series and then pulling in parallel...

Comment: Let's say you create a PR1 from branchA, then create a new branchAB (from branchA), and create a PR2 from it. When you review PR2, it includes the changes from both branchA and branchAB. This can be a lot. If you accept PR2, that will mark PR1 accepted too. Reviewing is hard. You should consider the reviewer, and create your PRs in nice smaller chunks that make good logical sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create **one** [branch](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) off of the master branch.

Then, for every set of your changes, just add a new commit onto your branch. This makes it easy to remove commits or view the changes for single commits if needed.

If master is updated, you can [rebase](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing) your one branch back ontop of master.

Comment: Yes, but when I submit a pull request, everything gets lumped together. Even though my branch has all of the commits, don't they only see the sum-total when I submit the PR? I do not have commit access, only the ability to submit pull requests.

Comment: If you want to pull down the changes in master, you do `git checkout master` then `git pull master`. One that is complete, you can rebase your branch ontop of master by doing `git checkout mybranch` then `git rebase master`

Comment: That's still not exactly what I'm looking for. What would make the most sense is to submit a particular commit out of a chain of commits as a separate pull request. For example, each separate commit would be a separate pull request.. but I'm pretty sure it needs to be a branch for a PR.

Comment: Downvote -- this answer ignores the point of the question. Zhro is asking about strategies for separate PRs that depend on each other. (The dependency here is not in the code, it's in the fact that he wants to squash bugs in series rather than parallel, but the result is the same.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for [interactive rebase](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html#_interactive_mode).  Make your changes on your own branch *however it  makes sense to you at the time*.  Then, when you're ready to have some of your work pulled, do an interactive rebase moving the ready changes to a commit series at the front of your branch, tag the last of them with a branch tip name so they can pull just those, and continue:

```
git checkout -b cleanup
# work work commit commit lalala
# others do the same on master

...o... .... X---Y     master   #
    \
     Mon-Tue-Wed-Thu   cleanup  # this branch not for publication
```

```
git rebase -i master
# (move commits and hunks as you like here, the whole point is you can
# work on an overview of a complete set of work and make it ready for 
# presentation/publishing)
```

```
...o... .... X---Y     master
                  \
                   A---B   for-upstream  # branch made during a rebase -i `edit` or `exec` stage
                        \
                         j---k---l   cleanup
```

Comment: Unless I'm misreading, this does not satisfy: ```To help simplify things for the author, I want to submit multiple pull requests for similar modifications in the code rather than one "lots of stuff cleaned up" so it will be easier for them to inspect and approve.```

Comment: @foobarbecue With interactive rebase you can arbitrarily reorder, split, and merge commits.  He can repeat the process as needed, generating multiple for-upstream pull points with exactly what's needed upstream at each, keeping the rest in the wip cleanup branch